# XML Node List as dependency property?

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have an xml file and have created controls to display the data within them.  Most of the displayed nodes don't have children, but a few do.  For the ones that do I need to list some attribute values in an ItemsControl.  I was able to create a List as a dependency property in order to test it and the strings showed up as expected.  However, now I'm trying to bind to the xml and it doesn't seem to be working.

I have changed the dependency property to List and bound this dependency property with the value SubOptions="{Binding Path=ChildNodes}".  Inside the control, the ItemsSource for the ItemsControl is also bound to its own dependency property.

Why would this not be working?  When I stuck a test converter on the binding, the value it was giving me was 'XmlChildNodes' which I can't create directly but every time I've tried to convert that to List implicitly it has worked...

Comment: Ok I tested putting a converter in between and converting from XmlNodeList to List<XmlNode> so that the types match exactly to the dependency property type.  I verified (in the debugger) that the list was created successfully, but I still get nothing in the ItemsControl...

Comment: How are you setting your DataContext?

Comment: Ok, I believe I found it.  For anyone else with this issue, here is what happened:

when using List<string> I was getting where the list was the same for every instance of the control on the form (so I couldn't have multiple instances of the control with different lists).  I searched here and found out that the dependency property for some reason uses the same list for each instance by default (dumb) but the solution was to put the code:

    SetValue(SubOptionsProperty, new List<string>());

Comment: in the constructor so that it sets to a new list.  This worked great for strings, but either the binding or the xml list apparently doesn't work that way, it seems it was setting the value from the binding, then this code in the constructor was dumping it and setting to a new list.  Interestingly, it does not use the same list and I can still have different lists on each control.

It seems to be working now after commenting out that line but if anyone has any more info I would love to know it...

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments, it won't let me answer myself yet...

Comment: Trevor the data context for the control is set in code behind and is working for the rest of the control, just couldn't figure out this list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe I found it.  For anyone else with this issue, here is what happened:

when using List I was getting where the list was the same for every instance of the control on the form (so I couldn't have multiple instances of the control with different lists).  I searched here and found out that the dependency property for some reason uses the same list for each instance by default (dumb) but the solution was to put the code:

```
SetValue(SubOptionsProperty, new List<string>());
```

in the constructor so that it sets to a new list.  This worked great for strings, but either the binding or the xml list apparently doesn't work that way, it seems it was setting the value from the binding, then this code in the constructor was dumping it and setting to a new list.  Interestingly, it does not use the same list and I can still have different lists on each control.

It seems to be working now after commenting out that line but if anyone has any more info I would love to know why it works...